# Dynamic height for Recharts horizontal barchart with long labels in YAxis

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, recharts

How can I change dynamically the height of my ResponsiveContainer in Recharts if the labels in the YAxis are too long?

This is my code:

```
                <ResponsiveContainer height={items.length * 50 + 10} width="100%">
                <BarChart
                    data={items}
                    margin={{top: 0, right: 40, left: 40, bottom: 20}}
                    layout="vertical"
                    barCategoryGap="20%"
                    barGap={2}
                    maxBarSize={10}

                >
                    <CartesianGrid
                        horizontal={false}
                        stroke='#a0a0a0'
                        strokeWidth={0.5}
                    />
                    <XAxis
                        type="number"
                        axisLine={false}
                        stroke='#a0a0a0'
                        domain={[0, 10]}
                        ticks={[0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10]}
                        strokeWidth={0.5}
                    />
                    <YAxis
                        type="category"
                        dataKey={this.props.YKey}
                        width={40}
                    />
                    <Bar
                        dataKey="score"
                        animationDuration={1000}
                        label={{position: 'right', backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
                        shape={<Rectangle
                            className={classes.rectangle}
                            radius={[0, 10, 10, 0]}
                        />}

                    >
                    </Bar>
                </BarChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
```

And this is how it looks like when the labels are too long:
[image]

I can calculate the height somehow with the length of the strings in the labels but I want to know if there is an "automatic" way of adapting the height of the responsive container if the labels in the YAxis are too long.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/ql20lrrkm6) is a codesandbox with some example data. The diagram should work with itemsEg1, itemsEg2 and itemsEg3.

Comment: Can you also provide with the `items` array? Or a codesandbox?

Comment: Just added a codesandbox. Check above :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to multiply the length of your items for your height- is there a special event that happens that requires this? You could just do `80%` or `100%` for height and it should adjust the height based on the percentage of the screen. A suggestion I would make though would be to also change the yAxis font-size if you can - this can make more room so the labels don't overlap- you can also add padding to the yAxis so the labels don't overlap as well.

Comment: Just added a codesandbox, check above. There you will see three examples of that that are normal in my application and why I cannot say height 100%.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I made some changes to your logic for the height in this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/7yzoxoln1q?fontsize=14

Also, thank you for the code sandbox! That really helped me see why you couldn't use the `height="100%"`

Comment: Unfortunately, the minTickGap={0} is not making any difference. If I increase the height till the long strings fit, they will of course fit but there is too much space for the short strings.