# How to style YAxis recharts to make it ellipsis if label too long?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Spec:

1. Recharts ver: 2.0.9
2. ReactJS ver: 17.0.2
3. Browser: Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (x86_64)
4. OS: MacOS

Background:

I'm trying to use [recharts](https://github.com/recharts/recharts) package to create a chart. I'm pretty close with my goal. But, I'm stuck in styling the YAxis Label to make it ellipsis if the label is too long.

Current Condition:

[image: Here is the current condition]

As you can see, it's overlapping with the other data. I know I can make the font-size smaller or set the width to be bigger. But, the problem is, the YAxis Label are dynamic and it could be long. Here is the current code https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-bar-chart-forked-72z60?file=/src/App.tsx

Objective:

I want to make the YAxis Label to display "This is long label and..." (showing three dots if it's too long), kind like using ellipsis.

Btw, I have same problem as this question [Dynamic height for Recharts horizontal barchart with long labels in YAxis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55942236/11871823). You may mark this as duplicate, but please, also help me. Those question still doesn't have accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it using one of `YAxis` props, `tickFormatter`. This props return each `YAxis` value and it's index. Also, this props need a string as the return value, which is formatted YAxis label. The idea is kind of like this:

```
tickFormatter = (value: string, index: number) => {
   const limit = 20; // put your maximum character
   if (value.length < limit) return value;
   return `${value.substring(0, limit)}...`;
};

<YAxis
   width={150}
   tickFormatter={tickFormatter}
/>
```

Comment: how to show the complete value on hover?